# trouble with an animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation

I subclassed a UIImageView. When it is double tapped, it will enlarge itself by 40%. I also have a UILabel that i place in the custom UIImageView and would like it to enlarge by 40%.

i can't seem to get it to animate correctly.

```
-(void)enlargeImage
{
    CGPoint pointCenter = self.center;
    CGPoint labelCenter = self.displayNameLabel.center;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:0
                        options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction) 
                     animations:^{
                     self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,
                                             self.frame.origin.y,
                                             self.frame.size.width * (1 + self.sizeMultiplier),
                                             self.frame.size.height * (1 + self.sizeMultiplier));
                         // Commented out after setting the autoresizeMask on the label
                         /*
                         self.displayNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.displayNameLabel.frame.origin.x,
                                                                  self.displayNameLabel.frame.origin.y,
                                                                  self.displayNameLabel.frame.size.width * (1 + self.sizeMultiplier),
                                                                  self.displayNameLabel.frame.size.height * (1 + self.sizeMultiplier));
                         */
                         self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
                     {
                         [self callDelegateSelect];
                     }];

    self.center = pointCenter;

    //self.displayNameLabel.center = labelCenter;
    //self.displayNameLabel.center = CGPointMake((self.frame.size.width / 2), (self.frame.size.height / 2));

    self.isSelected = TRUE;
}


-(void)shrinkImageWithZoomScale:(float)zoomScale
{
    CGPoint pointCenter = self.center;

    CGPoint labelCenter = self.displayNameLabel.center;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:0
                        options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                     animations:^{
                     self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,
                                             self.frame.origin.y,
                                             (self.originalHeight / zoomScale),
                                             (self.originalHeight / zoomScale));

                         // Commented out after setting the autoresizeMask on the label
                         /*
                         self.displayNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.displayNameLabel.frame.origin.x,
                                                                  self.displayNameLabel.frame.origin.y,
                                                                  ((self.originalLableHeight) / zoomScale),
                                                                  ((self.originalLableHeight) / zoomScale));
                         */
                         self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
                    {
                        [self callDelegateDeselect];
                    }];

    self.center = pointCenter;
    //self.displayNameLabel.center = labelCenter;
    //self.displayNameLabel.center = CGPointMake((self.frame.size.width / 2), (self.frame.size.height / 2));

    self.isSelected = FALSE;
}
```

the custom UIImageView animates exactly how i want it too, but the UILabel misbehaves.

unselected (UILabel's background is set to orange):

[image: unselected]

selected:

[image: selected]

i'm guessing since the UIImageView's point reference is changing, its messing up the points i'm telling the UILabel to be?

EDIT:

the custom UIImageView's:

```
self.autoresizesSubviews = TRUE;
```

the subview UILabel:

```
self.displayNameLabel.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
```

this solves the sizing issue, but it does not grow from the center; when growing, it shifts right and animates left to the center. when shrinking, it shifts left and animates right to the center. I also commented out setting the label's frame in the animation code.

Answer (score 1):

If the `UILabel` is a subview of the `UIImageView`, you could try to set the autoresizing options of the `UILabel` so that it resizes automatically when its superview does.

Also, make sure the `autoresizesSubviews` property of the `UIImageView` is set to `YES` (which is the default by the way).

Comment: Ok, i had set the autoresizeSubviews to true; didn't realize i needed to set autoresizingMask on the label, thank you. It doesn't completely solve the issue though. When it grows, the label shifts right and then moves left to the center. When it shrinks, it resizes and shifts left, then moves right to the center. I would like it to grow from the center and shrink to the center.

Comment: You can do this all with autoresizing masks and without tinkering with the label's `frame` in your `enlargeImage` method. You did remove that code, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, i commented out setting the UILabel's frame.